# No puedo estabecer un layout absoluto en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, layout, jpanel

Cree un proyecto en [netbeans-13](/questions/tagged/netbeans-13) con gradle en [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16) y al querer establecer un `JPanel` con un layout absoluto dándole clic izquierdo y "Set layout" absolute, no pasa nada (`Jframe` form), no se si es problema de mi netbeans o de la configuracion de proyecto.

Me muestra esto:

> A java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException exception has occurred.
> However, the system should continue working without further problems.
> Click Show Details for the stack trace.

Comment: y cuando le das click en details que te sale? PD: el absolute layout es propietario y no es por tanto un layout standard.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.